# REPLICAS remains 0 after running `docker stack deploy` command in manager machine

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine, docker-for-mac

I am using Docker for Mac and follow this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted-voting-app/deploy-app/)

Everything was fine until this [section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted-voting-app/deploy-app/#/deploy-the-app)

after I run this command

```
docker@manager:~$ docker stack services vote
```

the result shows:

```
docker@manager:~$ docker stack services vote
ID            NAME             MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
111ztgmjdwz1  vote_worker      replicated  0/1        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker:latest
jqp0bcz1z22t  vote_result      replicated  0/1       dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before
m5bhkh9i8d9q  vote_redis       replicated  0/2       redis:alpine
nizvjk9eqrqv  vote_db          replicated  0/1       postgres:9.4
p83dn7dwxbey  vote_visualizer  replicated  0/1       dockersamples/visualizer:stable
wd9wpxu34ooc  vote_vote        replicated  0/2       dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before
```

All REPLICAS is 0

Please help me to find out what the problem is.

UPDATE:

after I run the `stack ps` command, I get the information below:

```
docker@manager:~$ docker stack ps vote
ID            NAME               IMAGE                                         NODE     DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE            ERROR                             PORTS
rzvqbq8b71wu  vote_result.1      dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before  manager  Ready          Preparing 1 second ago                                     
zqieex49hgce  vote_redis.1       redis:alpine                                  manager  Ready          Preparing 2 seconds ago                                    
ysw0d0qfhz8w  vote_db.1          postgres:9.4                                  manager  Ready          Preparing 2 seconds ago                                    
g6c5p6u12foa  vote_vote.1        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    manager  Ready          Preparing 3 seconds ago                                    
5710hquichx3  vote_visualizer.1  dockersamples/visualizer:stable               manager  Running        Preparing 8 seconds ago                                    
b95jl8mc6x0l  vote_result.1      dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before  worker   Shutdown       Rejected 1 second ago    "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
9oloagv5j0nj  vote_redis.1       redis:alpine                                  worker   Shutdown       Rejected 2 seconds ago   "No such image: redis@sha256:f…"  
ouzyg0t3rasm  vote_db.1          postgres:9.4                                  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 2 seconds ago   "No such image: postgres@sha25…"  
k8dp3za2yj0o  vote_vote.1        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    worker   Shutdown       Rejected 3 seconds ago   "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
w53ql0mg265e  vote_result.1      dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 9 seconds ago   "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
3tcbd643jbxy  vote_db.1          postgres:9.4                                  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 11 seconds ago  "No such image: postgres@sha25…"  
tqv3iph2cumc  vote_vote.1        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    manager  Shutdown       Rejected 11 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
nglr0wfwwwp8  vote_visualizer.1  dockersamples/visualizer:stable               manager  Shutdown       Rejected 8 seconds ago   "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
203y30564uw6  vote_redis.1       redis:alpine                                  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 9 seconds ago   "No such image: redis@sha256:f…"  
vets2f9u9tg1  vote_result.1      dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before  worker   Shutdown       Rejected 16 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
1lo5to8md0xg  vote_db.1          postgres:9.4                                  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 17 seconds ago  "No such image: postgres@sha25…"  
o36ma9nyxlw1  vote_vote.1        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    worker   Shutdown       Rejected 18 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
e5fe36ipomb7  vote_visualizer.1  dockersamples/visualizer:stable               manager  Shutdown       Rejected 18 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
nl8c9wddg5am  vote_redis.1       redis:alpine                                  worker   Shutdown       Rejected 18 seconds ago  "No such image: redis@sha256:f…"  
8y04ilw2n5z1  vote_db.1          postgres:9.4                                  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 25 seconds ago  "No such image: postgres@sha25…"  
i1pia02saz87  vote_vote.1        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    manager  Shutdown       Rejected 25 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
ax65g1t9hzxn  vote_visualizer.1  dockersamples/visualizer:stable               manager  Shutdown       Rejected 25 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
ndwcahqjtmr8  vote_redis.1       redis:alpine                                  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 26 seconds ago  "No such image: redis@sha256:f…"  
yuf1y6nrsgow  vote_result.1      dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before  worker   Shutdown       Rejected 25 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
45mh7bjkdzjc  vote_visualizer.1  dockersamples/visualizer:stable               manager  Shutdown       Rejected 32 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
gvto5vlgwygx  vote_worker.1      dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker:latest  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 6 minutes ago   "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
b20cx84qj2uk   \_ vote_worker.1  dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker:latest  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 6 minutes ago   "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
srtdn6ym1ljl   \_ vote_worker.1  dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker:latest  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 6 minutes ago   "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
vca66fdph4mr   \_ vote_worker.1  dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker:latest  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 6 minutes ago   "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
0yy3anojajp4  vote_vote.2        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    manager  Ready          Preparing 4 seconds ago                                    
aofaaw9axob8  vote_redis.2       redis:alpine                                  manager  Running        Preparing 5 seconds ago                                    
7ac1vdmmueuo  vote_vote.2        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    worker   Shutdown       Rejected 4 seconds ago   "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
yp0mzgvxq0vt  vote_redis.2       redis:alpine                                  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 5 seconds ago   "No such image: redis@sha256:f…"  
s25a4llma3um  vote_vote.2        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    manager  Shutdown       Rejected 11 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
m1zwdm1cvuo7  vote_redis.2       redis:alpine                                  worker   Shutdown       Rejected 12 seconds ago  "No such image: redis@sha256:f…"  
uih8fypa0l55  vote_vote.2        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    worker   Shutdown       Rejected 19 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
b1zlxbt2f4hz  vote_redis.2       redis:alpine                                  manager  Shutdown       Rejected 26 seconds ago  "No such image: redis@sha256:f…"  
mfeig9kfly5s  vote_vote.2        dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before    manager  Shutdown       Rejected 28 seconds ago  "No such image: dockersamples/…"  
3rih1876aix9  vote_redis.2       redis:alpine                                  worker   Shutdown       Rejected 33 seconds ago  "No such image: redis@sha256:f…"
```

it seems docker can't download the image normally, but I still can get `docker run` command to work:

```
docker@manager:~$ docker run docker/whalesay cowsay hello
Unable to find image 'docker/whalesay:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from docker/whalesay
e190868d63f8: Pull complete 
909cd34c6fd7: Pull complete 
0b9bfabab7c1: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
00bf65475aba: Pull complete 
c57b6bcc83e3: Pull complete 
8978f6879e2f: Pull complete 
8eed3712d2cf: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:178598e51a26abbc958b8a2e48825c90bc22e641de3d31e18aaf55f3258ba93b
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker/whalesay:latest
 _______ 

 ------- 
    \
     \
      \     
                    ##        .            
              ## ## ##       ==            
           ## ## ## ##      ===            
       /""""""""""""""""___/ ===        
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~   
       \______ o          __/            
        \    \        __/             
          \____\______/
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have same issue as me. Seems that port 8080 is already busy, I found out that skype took it. So try to stop Skype and wait about a minute.

After this

```
docker@manager:~$ docker stack services vote
ID            NAME             MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
2xav0wm8ccnb  vote_redis       replicated  2/2       redis:alpine
89lfwfuaf967  vote_result      replicated  1/1       dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before
b5auc9630xbv  vote_db          replicated  1/1       postgres:9.4
evny2fz43rgc  vote_vote        replicated  2/2       dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before
ic7dgspefjdm  vote_worker      replicated  1/1       dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker:latest
suna584svdmr  vote_visualizer  replicated  1/1       dockersamples/visualizer:stable
docker@manager:~$
```